# Show a progress bar for downloading files using XHR2/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to download files using Ajax and show a custom **download progress bar.**

The problem is I can't understand how to do so. I wrote the code to log the progress but don't know how to initiate the download.

**NOTE:** The files are of different types.

Thanks in advance.

**JS**

```
// Downloading of files
filelist.on('click', '.download_link', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $(this).parent().addClass("download_start");

    $.ajax({
        xhr: function () {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            // Handle Download Progress
            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                if(evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                    console.log(percentComplete);
                }
            }, false);
            return xhr;
        },
        complete: function () {
            console.log("Request finished");
        }
    })
});
```

**HTML and PHP**

```
    <li>
    <div class="f_icon"><img src="' . $ico_path . '"></div>
    <div class="left_wing">
       <div class="progressbar"></div>
       <a class="download_link" href="#" id="'.$file_id.'"><div class="f_name">' . $full_file_name . '</div></a>
       <div class="f_time_size">' . date("M d, Y", $file_upload_time) . '&nbsp; &#149; &nbsp;' . human_filesize($file_size) . '</div>
    </div>

    <div class="right_wing">
       <div class="f_delete">
       <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#" aria-label="Delete" data-id="'.$file_id.'" data-filename="'.$full_file_name.'"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" title="Delete this?"></i>
       </a>
    </div>
   </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: How are you sending the file you've downloaded to the user?

Comment: If you are asking how am I downloading file, well that is what I want to know how should I download the file.

Comment: It looked like you were asking how to show the progress, but on second read, this is an extra to the download.  Simple answer: don't use ajax to download a file, use the browser.  `<a href='url to download' target='_blank'>download</a>`

Comment: Yes that can be obviously done but I need to show the download progress as it is the part of the UI

Comment: There's an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399641/ajax-page-download-progress but a better discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76976/how-to-get-progress-from-xmlhttprequest

Comment: @freedomn-m the first post is quite old but I went through the community wiki. But still I can't join the pieces of how to get it to work.

Comment: I'd worry about how to get the download prompted to the user first, before adding a progress bar.   General consensus is that it's not possible because that's now how ajax works.  eg:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35000500/send-radflowdocument-as-pdf-to-user/35000901#35000901  hence my first question in comments :)

Comment: Well, I have a list of files on a page with blank anchor tags wrapped arounf their filenames. On click of the filenames the background of the filename gets set to a different colour, which I use to show the progress.(Not sure if I got what you mean). I will update the question with the html.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want to show the user a progress-bar of the downloading process - you must do the download within the xmlhttprequest. One of the problems here is that if your files are big - they will be saved **in the memory** of the browser before the browser will write them to the disk (when using the regular download files are being saved directly to the disk, which saves a lot of memory on big files).

Another important thing to note - in order for the `lengthComputable` to be true - your server must send the `Content-Length` header with the size of the file.

Here is the javascript code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a1" data-filename="filename.xml">Click to download</div>
<script>
$('#a1').click(function() {
    var that = this;
    var page_url = 'download.php';

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", page_url, true);
    req.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
        if(evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
            console.log(percentComplete);
        }
    }, false);

    req.responseType = "blob";
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200) {
            var filename = $(that).data('filename');
            if (typeof window.chrome !== 'undefined') {
                // Chrome version
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(req.response);
                link.download = filename;
                link.click();
            } else if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
                // IE version
                var blob = new Blob([req.response], { type: 'application/force-download' });
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
            } else {
                // Firefox version
                var file = new File([req.response], filename, { type: 'application/force-download' });
                window.open(URL.createObjectURL(file));
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
});
</script>
```

And here is an example for the php code you can use:

```
<?php
$filename = "some-big-file";
$filesize = filesize($filename);

header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-Length:". $filesize);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment");

$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
if (FALSE === $handle) {
    exit("Failed to open stream to URL");
}

while (!feof($handle)) {
    echo fread($handle, 1024*1024*10);
    sleep(3);
}

fclose($handle);
```

> Note that I added a sleep to simulate a slow connection for testing on localhost.
>   You should **remove this** on production :)

Comment: Perfect example for _force download using ajax_

Comment: @Dekel this helped me a lot while tracking download speed per MB

Comment: @AhmedAli glad this helped :)

Comment: healthy and helpful example. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the file is big enough it's not good to put it in RAM. If it's small then a progressbar is not very usefull. This does not seem like a good idea. +1 for research and example.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but this won't work if downloading from a different domain, will it?

Comment: @bytrangle not sure what do you mean by "downloading from a different domain"

Comment: @Dekel: Sorry, I didn't notice that the method you used was POST, not GET, so I was talking about a different issue. Anyway, since you promptly reply, I'm risking asking a stupid question: Suppose you replace POST method with GET, and use a different domain as downloading url (e.g. domain-a.com) from the one your apps are hosted on (domain-b.com). If you don't control the server for `domain-a.com`, then you'll get an error "XMLHttpRequest blocked by CORS Policy", right?

Comment: @bytrangle, yes you are right (but this is less relevant for the current issue, so I suggest open a new question on that ;-) ).