# Is there a way to show Progress Bar for FTP downloads in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, download, ftp

I am able to download FTP files using CI controller function and need to know wheteher there is an option to indicate the progress bar of the  download.

The file just downloads and leaves no progress bar nor notification. Any comments?

Comment: may you use javascript or jQuery?

Comment: Yeah.. but I have no idea about it

Comment: you need to learn about AJAX, you can call your codeigniter file download function with an ajax call. Then you can use AJAX xhr to set the current length of your progress bar. You can start reading here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: and then here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39599878/2275490